# Aggregation fails on function that uses an index

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies for the simple question, I'm an R user who is relatively new to python.

Consider the following minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                              'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                              'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C' : range(0,8),
                   'D' : range(0,8)})
```

The following throws an error:

```
def myf(x):
    return x[2]

df[["A","C","D"]].groupby('A').aggregate(myf)
```

The desired output would be a pandas table like so:

```
| A     | myf C | myf D |
-------------------------
| foo   | 2     | 2     |
| bar   | 3     | 3     |
```

From the comments and the documentation, it seems like one can do something like:

```
def myf(x):
    return x.first
```

to get the first item, but it's not clear how one would construct a non-built in method that would still get the appropriate index value.  Something like:

```
def myf(x):
  return Series(x[1], index=x.index)
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you please provide numerical data and your desired output?

Comment: Hint: add `print(x)` inside your function, and then ask what you wanted `x[1]` to do with that `x`.

Comment: @Alexander I don't follow. I did provide numerical data. My question includes a minimal example data frame with numerical values generated randomly; the same example used in some of the `pandas` documentation.

Comment: But you don't provide the desired result, and the desired result cannot be inferred without the numerical data.

Comment: @Alexander ah, good point, I've now added specifically what the desired result would be for the example data provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Aggregation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) docs -

> Aggregating functions are ones that reduce the dimension of the returned objects, for example: mean, sum, size, count, std, var, sem, describe, first, last, nth, min, max. This is what happens when you do for example DataFrame.sum() and get back a Series.

If you follow @DSM's suggestion and add `print(x)` to `myf`, you'll see that you'll be passing a `Series` with the `index` from your original `DataFrame`. So if you generally ask for `x[1]`, some of the `Series` will not have that `index`.

You could do `return x.iloc[0]` so you rely on position, not label-based indexing. In other words, you select the first item in the grouped `Series`, not the one that happens to have the label '1' from the original `DataFrame`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I'm still a bit confused.  How could I then modify the above code to give back the first item in the list? (I've added my actual use case which is a slightly less trivial function to the question above as well; sorry for not posing a better question to start)

Comment: You could do `return x.iloc[0]` so you rely on position, not label-based indexing. In other words, you select the first item in the grouped `Series`, not the one that happens to have the label '1' from the original `DataFrame`.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.  Wasn't familiar with `iloc`.  Maybe add that to your answer so it's clear?